# Adding magento 2 order attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, sales-order, custom-attributes, custom-reports

I want to create an order attribute that creates a field in `sales_order_item` table also.
I want to insert some product-related data in this table which I want to filter later in sales report.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesOrder\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $orderItemsTable = 'sales_order_item';

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderItemsTable),
                'custom_attribute',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```